# Logstash can't stat org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit

Tags: java, ruby, logstash, elk, systemexit

Here is my mylogstash.conf file

```
input { 
    file { 
        path => "C:/elklogs/*.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
    } 
}

output {
    stdout{
        codec => rubydebug
    }

    elasticsearch { 
        host => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "mttestdata"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run logstash on windows 10 machine. logstash doesn't start, below error comes and stop the server. Please help me to solve this issue

```
C:\ELK\logstash\bin>logstash -f mylogstash.conf
"Using bundled JDK: C:\ELK\logstash\jdk\bin\java.exe"
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Sending Logstash logs to C:/ELK/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2022-07-27T19:31:54,916][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: C:\ELK\logstash\config\log4j2.properties
[2022-07-27T19:31:54,924][WARN ][logstash.runner          ] The use of JAVA_HOME has been deprecated. Logstash 8.0 and later ignores JAVA_HOME and uses the bundled JDK. Running Logstash with the bundled JDK is recommended. The bundled JDK has been verified to work with each specific version of Logstash, and generally provides best performance and reliability. If you have compelling reasons for using your own JDK (organizational-specific compliance requirements, for example), you can configure LS_JAVA_HOME to use that version instead.
[2022-07-27T19:31:54,925][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"8.3.2", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.20.1 (2.5.8) 2021-11-30 2a2962fbd1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.15+10 on 11.0.15+10 +indy +jit [mswin32-x86_64]"}
[2022-07-27T19:31:54,927][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] JVM bootstrap flags: [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=true, -Djruby.jit.threshold=0, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom, -Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true, -Djruby.regexp.interruptible=true, -Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true, --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/java.nio.channels=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED, --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED]
[2022-07-27T19:31:55,017][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2022-07-27T19:31:56,736][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600, :ssl_enabled=>false}
[2022-07-27T19:31:57,080][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 80 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 124 keys and 408 values
[2022-07-27T19:31:58,239][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Unknown setting 'host' for elasticsearch
[2022-07-27T19:31:58,250][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::IllegalStateException", :message=>"Unable to configure plugins: (ConfigurationError) Something is wrong with your configuration.", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.config.ir.CompiledPipeline.<init>(CompiledPipeline.java:120)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt.initialize(JavaBasePipelineExt.java:85)", "org.logstash.execution.JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.call(JavaBasePipelineExt$INVOKER$i$1$0$initialize.gen)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:837)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuper(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1169)", "org.jruby.ir.runtime.IRRuntimeHelpers.instanceSuperSplatArgs(IRRuntimeHelpers.java:1156)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InstanceSuperInvokeSite.invoke(InstanceSuperInvokeSite.java:39)", "C_3a_.ELK.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.java_pipeline.RUBY$method$initialize$0(C:/ELK/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:48)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:333)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:87)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:939)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", "C_3a_.ELK.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0(C:/ELK/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:50)", "C_3a_.ELK.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$__VARARGS__(C:/ELK/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:49)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", "C_3a_.ELK.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$block$converge_state$2(C:/ELK/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:381)", "org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)", "java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)"]}
[2022-07-27T19:31:58,350][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2022-07-27T19:31:58,358][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby.jar:?]
        at C_3a_.ELK.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(C:\ELK\logstash\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:91) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: Logstash notes that `No config files found in path {:path=>"C:/ELK/logstash/mylogstash.conf"}` Make sure you have named your config file correctly. In your question, you have written that it is named `mylogstash.cof` (without the n in conf).

Comment: Not only that the other case I got by reading your comment ,thanks for that.it is  NOT a host it should be hosts